# Can each node of selenium grid run different script/test? - how to setup?

Tags: python, testing, selenium

Can each node of selenium grid run different python script/test?
- how to setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use different browser configurations in the hub, and use two or more programs to contact the grid with different browsers

Comment: But I still doubt. For example
I have 2 scripts that are script1.py and script2.py which have different selenium commands and different operation. So I want to test script1 at port:5555 and script2 at port:5556.
Could you please give me some advice?? How to set up??

Comment: start two hubs with browser environments as Browser1 , Browser2 on ports 5555 & 5556. Now use Browser1 in script1.py & Browser2 in script2.py

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But now I have other problem.
I'm studying about selenium grid on Centos 6.3.
Assign computer A is hub and B,C are node when I start hub A then node B,C are done (working normally) 
but I can run python script for test a machine (node) which start first only.

Comment: How to solve this problem????? If I want to run python script in parallel (on 2 machines at the same time).

Webbrowser Version : Firefox 10.0.6
Start hub/node command 
A : java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -role hub
B : java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -role node -hub http://node A IP:4444/grid/register
C : java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -role node -hub http://node A IP:4444/grid/register -port 5556
Run script command :
python filename.py


I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: If you would like any further information, please don't hesitate to contact me. 
Any help is appreciate.